# How can I pack a BigInt treating four characters as an unsigned long in network byte order as Ruby's .pack(“N”) does, in Scala?

Tags: java, ruby, scala, endianness

Here is Ruby equivalent

```
[Digest::MD5.hexdigest("Data to pack").to_i(16)].pack("N")
```

Output: `"\x1AP0\\"`

The generated big integer is (md5 hash);

```
321255238386231367014342192054081171548
```

In Scala I got BigInt as follows;

```
def md5Hash(input: String): String = md5HashArr(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
def md5HashArr(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
    val digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    digest.reset()
    digest.update(bytes)
    digest.digest().map(0xFF & _).map {
      "%02x".format(_)
    }.foldLeft("") {
      _ + _
    }
  }

def hex2dec(hex: String): BigInt = {
    hex.toLowerCase().toList.map(
      "0123456789abcdef".indexOf(_)).map(
      BigInt(_)).reduceLeft(_ * 16 + _)
 }

def bytes2hexStr(bytes: Array[Byte], sep: String = ""): String = bytes.map("0x%02x".format(_)).mkString(sep)


val result: BigInt = hex2dec(md5Hash("Data to pack"))
val resultAsByteArray: Array[Byte] = result.toByteArray
```

Before converting to hex str as follows;

```
val hexStr:String = bytes2hexStr(resultAsByteArray)
```

How can I do the same in Scala?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i don't think scala has a direct equivalent for array.pack

Comment: A "bigint" is probably 8 bytes long, 64-bits, so are you intending to take only half the value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pack method, for BigNum in Ruby, will pack only last 32-bits(4-bytes). So, for this hash f1af822290cfcac4ce476a69**1a50305c**

```
[Digest::MD5.hexdigest("Data to pack").to_i(16)]
.pack("N")
.each_byte.map { |b| sprintf("0x%02X ",b) }.join
```

shows `0x1A 0x50 0x30 0x5C`, which are last 4bytes

Scala implementation with the same behaviour:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.nio._
import java.io._

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object MD5 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) =  {
    val str = "Data to pack"
    val md5Bytes = calcMd5(str)
    val md5Str = md5Bytes.map(b => "%02x".format(b)).mkString
    println(s"$str => $md5Str")

    // Get last 4-bytes
    val byteArr = md5Bytes.slice(12, 16)

    // Print it
    print(s"Last 4-bytes => ")
    byteArr.foreach { r =>
      print("%02X ".format(r))
    }
    println

  }  

  def calcMd5(str: String): Array[Byte] = {
    MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    .digest(str.getBytes)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ArtavazdBalayan for your answer and sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. Actually what I need is what Ruby `Array.pack('N')` does which is `"\x1AP0\\"` for `"Data to pack"` for example. here is the online sample in repl.it `https://repl.it/@ziyasal/DifferentUpsetHanumanmonkey`,

Comment: @ziyasal, fixed due what you need

Comment: thanks, that's clear, but how can I get bitstring representation like Ruby; for example output in this sample `"lorem ipsum dolor sit"` produces `"\xD1\xDF\x03["` and contains characters like `[` This was the problem actually I am struggling. For sample repl: repl.it/@ziyasal/DifferentUpsetHanumanmonkey

Comment: @ziyasal. It's just bytes, represented as string. Here is an example how to represent bytes as UTF-8 chars. It shows '�' if this char code is not exist for UTF-8 => https://repl.it/repls/QualifiedDamagedPanther. But I really don't understand why do you need to use string, not bytes.